# how to get start date and end date of sequence days in table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following columns:
1. User_Id
2. Work_Date

```
create table Test_Seq(user_id number, work_date date);
```

It has following data:

```
insert into Test_Seq values (1, '01-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (1, '02-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values  (1, '06-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (1, '09-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (1, '10-SEP-2013');

insert into Test_Seq values (2, '10-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (2, '26-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (2, '30-SEP-2013');
insert into Test_Seq values (2, '01-OCT-2013');
```

This table stores work_date for user. This work_date may or may not be in sequence.

There is one more table:

```
create table temp_holidys (holiday date);
insert into temp_holidys values ('27-SEP-2013');
insert into temp_holidys values ('31-DEC-2013');
```

I need queries / pl sql to get last Work_Date (order by desc) and its associated sequence start date; Sat and Sun are will not have any record but still they will be treated as in sequence (calendar days).

Same as we are treating Sat and Sun as part of sequence, it should treat day also in sequence if that day is in  temp_holidys table (see #2 below).

1. For user_id 1,  this should give me '10-SEP-2013' as end date and '06-SEP-2013' as start date
2. For user_id 2,  this should give me '01-OCT-2013' as end date and '26-SEP-2013' as start date (27-OCT-2013 needs to be treated as in sequence as it is defined in temp_holidys table)
3. It has to be sequence meaning if for example in # 1, for user id 1, if there was no record for '09-SEP-2013', it should return '10-SEP-2013' for start date. Also in #2, for user 2, if there was no record on '26-SEP-2013', it should return 30-SEP-2013' for start date.

Comment: Can you describe more the third, condition?

Comment: Desired output is this? 1, '01-SEP-2013', '02-SEP-2013' *** 1, '06-SEP-2013', '10-SEP-2013' *** 2, '10-SEP-2013', '10-SEP-2013' *** 2, '26-SEP-2013', '01-OCT-2013'

Comment: Please add the desired output based on the sample data.

Comment: @ Gatej Alexandru - #3 is actually additional requirements for #1 and #2.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner - a function which will accept user id and it will return start date and end date as per requirements (#1, #2 and #3)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : a function which will accept user id and it will return start date and end date as per requirements (#1, #2 and #3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach.

- In this approach, all the working days, holidays and weekends are put together in the same table.
- Then the starting of each sequence is identified with dates ordered in descending order.
- Each sequence is given a number.
- Max and Min of first sequence is found out, which is the required result.

Here's the query for user 1.

```
/*---for user 1---*/
with minmaxdays as(
  --find the latest and earliest working date for each user
  select min(work_date) min_date,
         max(work_date) max_date
  from test_seq
  where user_id = 1
  ),
alldays as(
  --generate all days from earliest to latest dates
  select min_date + level all_days
  from minmaxdays
  connect by min_date + level < max_date
  ),
combined_test_seq as(
  --get the working days
  select work_date working_days, 'W' date_type  --W indicates working days
  from test_seq
  where user_id = 1
  union all
  --get the holidays
  select holiday working_days, 'H' date_type   --H indicates holidays/weekends
  from temp_holidys
  union all
  --get all the weeknds
  select all_days working_days, 'H' date_type   --H indicates holidays/weekends
  from alldays
  where to_char(all_days,'D') in ('1','7')      --select only saturdays and sundays
  ),
grouping as(
--find out the beginning of each sequence
  select working_days,
         date_type,
         case when working_days + 1 = 
                   lag(working_days,1) over (order by working_days desc)
              then 0
              else 1
         end seq_start
  from combined_test_seq
  ),
grouping2 as(
--assign sequence no, and keep only the working days
  select working_days,
         sum(seq_start) over (order by working_days desc) grp
  from grouping
  where date_type = 'W'
  )
-- get the max and min date in the first sequence.
select max(working_days) keep (dense_rank first order by grp),
       min(working_days) keep (dense_rank first order by grp)
from grouping2;
```

Result:

```
max(date)       min(date)
-------------------------
10-SEP-2013     06-SEP-2013
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31d21/6).

Answer (score 0):

you need a PL/SQL function. Either one that gives you the pipelined output or one that tells you if days are following each other. Here is a solution for the second way:

This is the function needed. It returns 0 for false and 1 for true, due to the lack of a boolean data type in Oracle SQL:

```
create or replace function are_dates_adjacent(vi_start_date date, vi_end_date date) return number as
  v_count integer;
begin
  -- Same day or next day is of course in sequence with the start day
  IF trunc(vi_end_date) in ( trunc(vi_start_date), trunc(vi_start_date) + 1 ) then
    return 1; -- TRUE
  -- An end day before start day is invalid
  elsif trunc(vi_end_date) < trunc(vi_start_date) then
    return 0; -- FALSE
  end if;

  -- Now loop through the days between first and last to look out for gaps, i.e. skipped working days
  for offset in 1 .. trunc(vi_end_date) - trunc(vi_start_date) - 1 loop
    -- If Saturday or Sunday, then we are fine with this, otherwise let's see if it's a holiday
    if to_char(trunc(vi_start_date) + offset, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') not in ('SAT','SUN') then
      -- If it's neither Saturday or Sunday nor a holiday then return false
      select count(*) into v_count from temp_holidys where holiday = trunc(vi_start_date) + offset;
      if v_count = 0 then 
        return 0; -- FALSE
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;

  -- No gap detected; return true
  return 1; -- TRUE
end;
```

Here is the select statement. In the ordered list it first looks for group changes, i.e. a user changes or the dates are not considered adjacent. Based on this groups are built, so that at last we can find the first ands last date per group.

```
select user_id, min(work_date), max(work_date)
from
(
  select user_id, work_date, sum(group_change) over(order by user_id, work_date) as date_group
  from
  (
    select
      user_id, 
      work_date, 
      case when
        user_id  nvl(lag(user_id) over(order by user_id, work_date), user_id) or
        are_dates_adjacent(nvl(lag(work_date) over(order by user_id, work_date), work_date), work_date) = 0 
      then 1 else 0 end as group_change
    from Test_Seq
    order by user_id, work_date
  )
)
group by user_id, date_group
order by user_id, min(work_date);
```

EDIT: And here is the select statement giving you only the last working time for one user.

```
select start_date, end_date
from
(
    select min(work_date) as start_date, max(work_date) as end_date
    from
    (
        select work_date, sum(group_change) over(order by work_date) as date_group
        from
        (
            select
                work_date, 
                case when
                    are_dates_adjacent(nvl(lag(work_date) over(order by work_date), work_date), work_date) = 0 
                then 1 else 0 end as group_change
            from Test_Seq
            where user_id = 1
            order by work_date
        )
    )
    group by date_group
    order by min(work_date) desc
)
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help but I need to know start date and end date as mentioned in my post.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read thoroughly it seems. I am adding a select statement to get only one user and only his last working time.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please show the desired output? That will help.

I tried to comprehend your query and came up with this -

```
select distinct * from 
(
select user_id, min(work_date) over (partition by user_id) start_date, max(work_date) over (partition by user_id) end_date  
from test_seq t
where not exists (select null from temp_holidys h
                         where h.holiday=t.work_date)
)
```

Thanks, Aditya